# When I go to create a managed user, I receive a "Requested registry access is not allowed." error message

Tags: user-profile-service, windows-7, managed-account

I'm trying to add a maanged user account to the SharePoint install on my development machine.  My development machine is running Windows 7 and is linked to our domain.

Right now, I only have 2 managed accounts: network service and local system.  For me to try to do user profile synchronization, I need to specify a managed account with a password.  Trying to create an account induces this error message.

I did some googling and found that some people do regedit and give the SharePoint groups WSS_ADMIN_WPG and WSS_WPG full control over 14.0 and Office Server nodes in Microsoft in SOFTWARE under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

Despite doing this, it still gives  a required access denied error message.  Any reason why?

Also, when I try to find the correlation id, there don't seem to be any logs.

Comment: I agree with Wictor, although Procmon from SysInternals will help you track down permissions issues in future

Answer (score 1):

running SharePoint Server 2010 on Windows 7 is generally a bad idea and especially if you're using Local System and Network Service!

To successfully run the User Profile Service App you need proper domain accounts.

Don't waste your time to get this to work. Invest in a virtual machine (Hyper-V, VMWare, VHD boot) and run it on Windows Server with proper domain accounts.